# How to get X value of chart in lightningchart on mousemove

Tags: lightningchart

i want to get x value of chart when mouse is moved over the chart

```
 chart[key].onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove((obj, ev)=>{

console.log('test');
    const point = obj.engine.clientLocation2Engine(ev.clientX, ev.clientY)
    const onScale = translatePoint(point, obj.engine.scale, {x:obj.getDefaultAxisX(), y:obj.getDefaultAxisY()})
    
    }
```

above code works only when i keep mouse over empty area , if mouse is moved over line series this function is not called.P.s there are multiple line series in chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series have their own events, or alternatively you can disable them from mouse tracking entirely with `setMouseInteractions(false)`